# How to prevent character unescaping with WebClient or HttpWebRequest or any .NET client?

Tags: system.net

I am making a request to http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-ES to get an audio recording.  When I use System.Net.WebClient, System.Net.Http.HttpClient or WebRequest.Create, the request is sent as [http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=daño&tl=es-ES](http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-ES) instead.  This second url works, but produces a incorrect result.

How can I send a request with %C3%B1 instead of ñ in the path?

Note that you cannot download these urls with a referral header (like, by clicking them) so if you click them they will fail and the result may be cached so that copy'n'pasting the url fails too.  If you want to test the urls, copy them to the clipboard, then add to the q parameter to avoid cached results.

Adding repro where I tried using PUrify (same results as without):

```
            var parameters = this.Bind<SpeechRequest>();
            parameters.q = "daño";
            parameters.tl = "es-MX";

            var url = String.Format("http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q={0}&tl={1}", 
                WebUtility.UrlEncode(parameters.q), WebUtility.UrlEncode(parameters.tl));

            var uri = new Uri(url);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Uri constructed from string: " + url);
            System.Console.WriteLine("Before Purify: ");
            ShowUriDetails(uri);
            uri.Purify();
            System.Console.WriteLine("After Purify:");
            ShowUriDetails(uri);

            var request = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
```

Output:

```
    Uri constructed from string: http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
    Before Purify:
            uri.ToString() - http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=daño&tl=es-MX
            uri.AbsoluteUri - http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
            uri.Host - translate.google.com
            uri.Query - ?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
            uri.PathAndQuery - /translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
            uri.AbsolutePath - /translate_tts
            uri.Fragment -
    After Purify:
            uri.ToString() - http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=daño&tl=es-MX
            uri.AbsoluteUri - http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
            uri.Host - translate.google.com
            uri.Query - ?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
            uri.PathAndQuery - /translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-MX
            uri.AbsolutePath - /translate_tts
            uri.Fragment -
```

Comment: maybe I'm missing something here, but would htmlencoding the url be enough to fix it?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3te6wfz(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I just used WebRequest and the URL is not changed. `GET http://translate.google.com/translate_tts?q=da%C3%B1o&tl=es-ES HTTP/1.1`

Comment: @user2366842 I'll put in sample code to show how I am url encoding the special characters

Comment: @Brianfromstatefarm how did you observe it hadn't change?  Which namespace is your WebRequest from?

Comment: Oh geez.  After looking at it closer in Fiddler, I found the problem was the different in User-Agent :(